# Resetting to factory default on a Gigamon GigaVUE-212

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

I purchased the above-mentioned GigaVUE-212 for my test lab from eBay, to determine if I want to use them in production.  However, the thing doesn't respond to the default passwords, and I can't figure out how to reset from the console.  I do have access to the RedBoot loader, but their documentation is super vague about it.

I'm contacting support as well, and will leave an answer here if they have one for me other than "welp, that's why you don't use eBay", but my hope is someone else has been down this road.

Comment: The support answer is that I need to provide a statement from the original owner saying they've sold it to me, along with some money for a new warranty.  Geez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to totally reset to factory:

1. Connect a serial port, 115200/8/N/1, no flow control
2. Reboot the device.  Hit control-C when it mentions RedBoot (I just kept tapping ^c during boot until it worked)
3. At the `RedBoot>` prompt, type `fconfig rstrtac true`, then answer `y` when it asks `Update RedBoot non-volatile configuration - continue (y/n)?`
4. Reboot again, and log in with root/root123

Answer (score 1):

For Gigamon Gigavue-MP, the steps from Bill Weiss above will give you access to the cli.

However the config and prior saved config files are still present

```
reset system factory-default
delete file <tab-auto-complete-list-of-files>
```